# Graylog2: Custom index name format

Tags: elasticsearch, graylog2, graylog

Currently all my indexes have following pattern - **graylog_*** , so new indexes are created like graylog_0, graylog_1, graylog_2 ...

I didnt find anything related to index name in */etc/graylog/server/server.conf*

Except such as fields:

```
elasticsearch_index_prefix = graylog2
elasticsearch_template_name = graylog-interval
```

I also changed `rotation_strategy` to **time** -- but this didnt help.

So is there any config file either in Graylog2 Web Interface, or somewhere in file configuration, so indexes would have name like

```
graylog_2016-09-20-3:17pm
graylog_2016-09-21-3:17pm
```

Answer (score 0):

That's currently not possible with Graylog (as of Graylog 2.1.1).